# Javascript error while expanding product categories on Prestashop 1.6 backoffice

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a Prestashop 1.6.1.14 shop and at the backoffice when I'm adding a new product and I try to expand all the categories available to associate with the new product I get this error:

```
VM837:33 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'parent' of null
at organizeTree (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:33:32)
at Object.eval [as success] (eval at <anonymous> (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2), <anonymous>:195:6)
at j (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:2)
at x (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
at XMLHttpRequest.b (jquery-1.11.0.min.js:4)
```

Any ideas on how to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Try to **disables non Prestashop modules** in

> Advanced Preferences > Performances

and refresh your cache, see if issue comes from external plugins